# Why is CMake/MSBuild changing the parallel compilation setting /MP

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, msbuild

I'm using CMake with Visual Studio (i.e MSBuild).  I have the `/MP` setting across the board, but running on various machines with 8, 16, 32 physical cores, I'm seeing `/MP1` being set when `cl.exe` is called.

Why is my desire to use all cores possible not being respected?

**Update**

If I provide a value to /MP i.e /MP8, I then get /MP8.  For some reason however /MP seems to result in /MP1 even though I have many cores than this.